# Emperical plotting positions for General Pareto using extRemes

Tags: r, statistics

I have been working with `extRemes` and have a question about a formula it uses in the source code.

To calculate the emperical plotting distributions for a General Pareto model [source](https://github.com/cran/extRemes/blob/a9e02e7f2c77227e3dd920488b5dca35c017fef5/R/fitdiagnostics.R#L4523) it uses this equation:

```r
transform.points = -1/log(xp2)[sdat > u]/x$npy
```

where `xp2` is the probability ploting ordinates for the input data, `sdat` is the sorted input data, `u` is the specified threshold and `x$py` is the time units for the analysis.

My question is: Why are the plotting positions calculated as the inverse of log transformed values?

Why wouldn't the inverse of the probability plotting ordinates be used? Something like:

```r
transform.points = 1/xp2[sdat > u]/x$npy
```

Comment: Before others suggest it, I found that you already [posted this on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/500117/empirical-plotting-positions-for-general-pareto-using-extremes).